# matlab function using excel colums definiton of x

Tags: matlab

If you want matlab to describe a function y=f(t) with t being the independent variable. This function has 8 parameters that differ based on the subject.

These 8 parameters are listed columnwise in an excel column uploaded in a matlab file and called upon by

```
m1=xlsread('jongens0','A:A');
```

and this for all eight parameters

I need the differentiated curve of my function y=f(t) zo i defined my independent variable t

```
tmin=0;
tmax=20;
dt=1/100;
t = tmin:dt:tmax;
```

Problem is that t seems to be a 1*200 vector by this convention, whereas my parameters are 50*1 column vectors so if i try to multiply them. How can I make t act like the independent variable of a function?

or do i need to put this into a function editor? Instead of the command script?

I'm a real noob at programming so my apologies if the question is downward stupid :-)

Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of dt is incorrect.  It should be:

```
 dt = (tmax-tmin)/(length(m1)-1);
```

Comment: thanks, 
I see that my t changed from 1*200 to a 1*50 value. However all my m1 to m8 are presented as columns. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to change a column vector into a row vector?  If so, just transpose it.  m1=m1';